# problem uploading video to express in expo react native

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo, multipartform-data

I'm going to upload video to express backend
and then from express to firebase storage.
backend is perfect now
but I can't upload to backend my video.

I'm using expo-file-picker.
I need to send the file using formdata
like

```js
data = new FormData();
....
```

this is my frontend part, expo react native

```js
const pickVideoAsync = async () => {
    const result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Videos,
      allowsEditing: true,
    });

    if (!result.canceled) {
      setFormData({
        ...formData,
        video: [...formData.videos, result],
      });
      setTempVideos((prev) => [...prev, result.uri]);
    } else {
      Toast.warn("You didn't select any video.");
    }
  };

  const handleUpdate = async () => {
    const { title, price, size, category, description, images } = formData;
    if (!title || !price || !size || !category || !description) {
      Toast.warn("Please fill out the all inputs");
      return;
    }
    if (!images.length && !originImages.length) {
      Toast.warn("You need to choose at least 1 image");
      return;
    }

    setIsLoading(true);
    try {
      const accessToken = await SecureStore.getItemAsync("accessToken");

      const data = new FormData();
      data.append("product_id", id);
      data.append("title", formData.title);
      data.append("price", formData.price);
      data.append("size", formData.size);
      data.append("cat_id", formData.category);
      data.append("description", formData.description);
      // formData?.images?.map(image=> {
      //   data.append("images", image);
      // })
      data.append("images[]", formData.images);
      formData?.videos?.map(video=>{
        data.append("videos", video)
      })

      data.append("originImages[]", originImages);
      data.append("originVideos[]", originVideos);

      const res = await axios.post(baseUrl + "/api/product/update", data, {
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "x-access-token": accessToken,
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        },
      });
      if (res.data?.success) {
        Toast.success(res.data.message);
        navigation.push("/profile");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.response.status === 400) {
        Toast.error("Input the all fields correctly");
      } else {
        console.log(error.response.data);
        Toast.error("Something went wrong...");
      }
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };
```

this is routes for express

```js
import {
  deleteProduct,
  getAllProductsCategories,
  getAllProductsByProfile,
  getAllProductsCategoriesByuserId,
  getProductByCategory,
  getProductBylike,
  getProductDetail,
  likeProduct,
  saveProduct,
  updateProduct,
  getCategories,
  getProductByCategoryByUser,
  saveProductTest
} from "../controllers/product.controller";
import { authJwt } from "../middlewares";
import multer from "multer";

const storage = multer.memoryStorage();
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

export default function (app) {
  app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
      "x-access-token, Origin, Content-Type, Accept"
    );
    next();
  });

  app.get("/api/items", getAllProductsCategories);
  app.get(
    "/api/items/filter",
    [authJwt.verifyToken],
    getAllProductsCategoriesByuserId
  );
  app.post(
    "/api/product/save",
    [authJwt.verifyToken, upload.array("videos")],
    saveProduct
  );
  app.post(
    "/api/product/savetest",
    [ upload.array("videos")],
    saveProductTest
  );
  app.post(
    "/api/product/update",
    [authJwt.verifyToken, upload.array("videos")],
    updateProduct
  );
  app.post("/api/product/delete", [authJwt.verifyToken], deleteProduct);
  app.post("/api/product/like", [authJwt.verifyToken], likeProduct);
  app.get("/api/product/bylike", [authJwt.verifyToken], getProductBylike);
  app.get(
    "/api/product/profile",
    [authJwt.verifyToken],
    getAllProductsByProfile
  );
  app.get("/api/product/bycategory/:cat_id", getProductByCategory);
  app.get(
    "/api/product/bycategorybyuser/:cat_id",
    [authJwt.verifyToken],
    getProductByCategoryByUser
  );
  app.get("/api/product/detail/:product_id", getProductDetail);
  app.get("/api/categories", getCategories);

}
```

this is controller

```js
async function saveProduct(req, res) {
  //Form Valdiation
  console.log(req.body)
  const { errors, isValid } = ValidateProductInput(req.body);
  if (!isValid) {
    return res.status(400).json(errors);
  }

  const { images, title, price, description, cat_id, size } = req.body;
  console.log(req.body);

  console.log("video----", req.files);

  let imageUrls;
  if (images?.length) {
    imageUrls = await Promise.all([
      ...images?.map((image, key) => {
        return uploadProductImgToFirebase(image, Date.now() + title + key);
      }),
    ]);
  }

  let videoUrls;
  if (req.files?.length) {
    videoUrls = await Promise.all([
      ...req.files?.map((video, key) => {
        return uploadProductVideoToFirebase(video, Date.now() + title + key);
      }),
    ]);
  }

  console.log(imageUrls);
  console.log(videoUrls);
  new Product({
    user_id: req.id,
    images: imageUrls,
    videos: videoUrls,
    title: title,
    price: price,
    description: description,
    cat_id: cat_id,
    size: size,
  })
    .save()
    .then((product) => {
      return res.json({
        success: true,
        message: "Your product has been added.",
        data: product,
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}
```

image uploading is good
but video is always empty array via multer middleware.

I want to upload this videos to firebase

```js
async function uploadProductVideoToFirebase(data, name) {
  const filepath = `${mainFolder}/${productFolder}/${name}${".mp4"}`;
  const file = bucket.file(filepath);

  try {
    await file.save(data.buffer, {
      contentType: data.mimetype,
    });
    console.log("Uploaded a video file to Firebase!");

    const [url] = await file.getSignedUrl({
      action: "read",
      expires: "03-01-2500", // This is just an arbitrary far-future date.
    });

    return url;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error:", err);
    throw err;
  }
}
```